# Variable interpolation for type map

Tags: terraform

Upgraded to terraform v0.12.2 and most of the things stopped working straight way. (my bad, I didn't check this page: https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html prior to upgrade)

Anyway, fixed most of the things but the variable interpolation of type `map` still not working. in pre-v012.x, this would work perfectly:

#### *security_groups.tf*

```
// SecurityGroup: default access
resource "aws_security_group" "default" {
  count        = "${length(var.s_zones)}"
  vpc_id       = "${element(aws_vpc.vpcs.*.id, count.index)}"
  name         = "${var.vpc_names[count.index]}-default"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${var.vpn_cidrs["lan"]}",
                   "${var.vpn_cidrs["ovp"]}"]
    description = "SSH from vpn"
  }
}
```

#### *vars.tf*

```
// Variable: vpn_cidrs
variable "vpn_cidrs" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    lan = ["10.0.11.0/28", "10.0.12.0/28"]
    ovp = ["10.1.13.0/28", "10.1.14.0/28"]
  }
}
```

With v0.12.2, it returns:

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
>
> on ../../modules/vpc/security_groups.tf line 55, in resource
>   "aws_security_group" "default": 55: cidr_blocks =
>   ["${var.vpn_cidrs["lan"]}",
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": element 0: string
>   required.

I tried using the new constructor:

```
// Variable: vpn_cidrs
variable "vpn_cidrs" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    lan1 = "10.0.11.0/28",
    lan2 = "10.0.12.0/28",
    ovp1 = "10.1.13.0/28",
    ovp2 = "10.1.14.0/28",
  }
}
```

But then I cannot figure out how to use that for SG rules in the module. Anyone knows what am I missing or how to fix that? Really stuck since Friday evening. Any pointed, example-code would be highly appreciated.

-S

Comment: nope, it doesn't work, simply just removing the `[]` either from the variable: vpn_cidrs or the ingress{} rule. Already tried that. Unless I'm terribly missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

`"${var.vpn_cidrs["lan"]}"` returns the **list** `["10.0.11.0/28", "10.0.12.0/28"]`, but a **string** is required as the error message states.

Try using `"${join(", ", var.vpn_cidrs["lan"])}"` to generate the string `10.0.11.0/28, 10.0.12.0/28`.

To generate a combined list of the two lists *vpn_cidrs["lan"]* and *vpn_cidrs["ovp"]*, use the `concat()` function (see [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/concat.html)).

```
cidr_blocks = "${concat(var.vpn_cidrs["lan"], var.vpn_cidrs["ovp"])}"
```

This generates `["10.0.11.0/28", "10.0.12.0/28", "10.1.13.0/28", "10.1.14.0/28"]`

Comment: Thanks @rflume! that seems work but not sure until when `map(string)` variable type will be enforced. On a related matter, instead of using `[lan]`, `[ovp]` staticly, is there a way to get all the keys dynamically? The intension is to make it as a shared module, so that different teams can use their own sets of  key/value pair.